# Efficient SQL database design for recording examples of a word

Tags: database-design

I am designing a dictionary-like program which stores (and displays) a few example sentences of the given word. One way to design a SQL database for such problem is to create a table with two columns `word` and `example` and then for each example sentence add a new row with the repeated word in the column `word`. Is this approach common and efficient? I was also thinking of dynamically creation of a table of examples for each word and then relate the table to the word somehow. Is this approach better than previous one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go 1 step further from the other suggestions and take the example sentance into a new table as well. As a sentance is made up of many words the same sentance could be used for different words.

```
Word
=======
Word_Id INT Identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Word nvarchar(50) not null

ExampleSentance
========
Sentance_Id INT Identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Senatnce nvarchar(MAX) not null

Word_ExampleSentance
========
Word_Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
Sentance_Id INT PRIMARY KEY
```

When selecting a word and all the sample sentances you just need to join the tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Word
JOIN   Word_ExampleSentance 
  ON   Word.Word_Id = Word_ExampleSentance.Word_Id
JOIN   ExampleSentance 
  ON   ExampleSentance.Sentance_Id = Word_ExampleSentance.Sentance_Id
```

Comment: The three table approach seems a bit dangerous -- if you have one example sentence that pertains to 10 words, and you change the sentence so that it effectively only applies to 8 now instead of 10, you have to remove the two broken associations. A two table approach forces you to keep your sentence tied directly to one word. I suppose it depends entirely on the nature of the application and any storage space requirements, but it's just a thought.

Comment: @Cory: I see your point. However, I think that I can handle such danger with three table approach by checking the existence of the word in the modified example sentence and add/remove the associated words to.

Comment: @Rasoul: I just wanted to make it a point, that's all! I'm sure you will find a way to maintain valid associations :)

Comment: @Cory: Good point. I hadn't considered that. As Rasoul mentioned, if you knwo about it you can code around it, but it's certainly something to keep in mind

Answer (score 2):

I would have 2 tables: Word: word_id, word

Then Example: word_id,example_sentence

This will likely be more efficient in terms of storage since you only need 4 bytes to store an id and possibly many more to store duplicates of a word.

Comment: The three table approach seems a bit dangerous -- if you have one example sentence that pertains to 10 words, and you change the sentence so that it effectively only applies to 8 now instead of 10, you have to remove the two broken associations. A two table approach forces you to keep your sentence tied directly to one word. I suppose it depends entirely on the nature of the application and any storage space requirements, but it's just a thought.

Comment: @Cory I agree and I thought of that and you are right, it's a dangerous design if not handled with care. I will remove the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you would need two tables:

```
Word
=====
Id     (primary key, int, identity)
Word   (a string type, not null, unique)
```

And

```
WordExample
===========
Id       (primary key, int, identity) (optional, not used in this example)
WordId   (foreign key to Word.Id)
Sentence (a string type, not null)
```

(or however you'd like to appropriately name them).

This approach prevents storing each word multiple times in the same table. To query for all examples for a word, you add a `JOIN` to your query:

```
SELECT
    w.[Word], we.[Sentence]
FROM
    [Word] w
LEFT JOIN
    [WordExample] we ON w.[Id] = we.[WordId]
WHERE
    w.[Word] = 'abc'
```